# Chrome flagged a website as insecure and it is asking for my credit card details

Tags: tls

I verified that the root CA `AddTrust External CA Root` is installed in the Windows 10 certificate store. How else can I fix this from a client perspective ?

```
$ openssl s_client -connect service.electrostub.com:443 -tls1_2
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, 
    O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.electrostub.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA 
Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA 
Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority  
2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority    
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to fix this from a client perspective, because it's not broken on the client. It's broken on the server.

Comment: There are a number of reasons Chrome might flag a website as insecure; you need to provide more information about that for this question to be approachable.  In Chrome, hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools, then click on the "Security" tab to see what Chrome is actually complaining about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

First, `openssl s_client` is not using the Windows certificate store but requires a certificate store in a different format and in a different location - and commonly there is nothing installed there on Windows. That's why it cannot find the root CA in the local trust store which results in the error message you see.

But, the certificate validates correctly in Edge, IE and Chrome since these all use the Windows builtin trust store. And while Firefox does not use the OS builtin trust store it ships with its own which also contains the required root CA.

The real reason the site is reported is insecure is because it forwards HTTPS traffic to plain HTTP. This means while it has a valid and properly installed SSL certificate and could in theory use HTTPS to protect the connection it explicitly abandons HTTPS and forces the browser to use plain unprotected and insecure HTTP:

```
$ curl -v https://service.electrostub.com
...
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
< Location: http://service.electrostub.com/index.cfm?
            ^^^^^
```

If this is by design or because of a misconfiguration of the site I don't know, although misconfiguration is more likely. From the client side there is nothing you could do to fix this problem. Instead it needs to be fixed by the operators of the server.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those gray areas, IMHO. I see this somewhat infrequently, and each time it baffles me. You seem to know what it means - so I'll skip any explanation. :)

It is not something I'd even try to fix from client-side - unless I know that the specific certificate (including its serial number and finger prints) matches with my local certificate store's copy. It's possible that the same intermediate CA (AddTrust External CA, in this case) may have other certificates (that are not in local cert store) in use.

Aside: That specific site is redirecting https to http. So giving credit card information is definitely not recommended - even if the payments page is served with https.